# Algorithm to determine the maximum sum array by complementing bit mask

Tags: arrays, algorithm

This question posed by my co-worker bamboozled me. I cannot even come up with a clean brute-force solution. To state the problem:

Given an array of size `n` containing non-negative integers, `k = [10, 40, 1, 200, 5000, ..., n]`,  a bit mask of size `n`, i.e. `mask = 1001....b_n where |mask| = n.` and an integer representing contiguous bits that can be complemented `S = 3`, find a configuration of mask that yields maximum sum array.

The complement size `S` is used to pick `S` contiguous bit from the bit mask and replacing it by its complement.

For example, if `mask = 100001` with `S = 2` you could

- Change `mask` to `010001` by applying the mask at MSB
- You can iteratively  keep on complementing at any bit in the `mask` till you find array of maximum size.

Here is what I've come up:

1. Find all the `2^n` bit mask configurations then apply them to find the maximum sum array
2. Given the initial mask configuration see if there exists a path to the maximum sum array configuration found in step 1.

Again mine is an exponential solution. Any efficient ones are appreciated.

Comment: I’d sum each bit position independently and fiddle with the mask at the end. Also there are only `{n \choose S}` possibilities for the mask. If `S` is about `n/2`, this is still exponentially large number, but maximization of the sum may prune the possibilities substantially.

Comment: Sorry I am afraid I do not how you can prune effectively here.

Comment: @kuriouscoder Would an algorithm with complexity `O(n * 2^S)` do? That's doable with a DP on the state space of indices `x` "mask of applied masks". (That's probably cryptic. Let me know if that suffices and I will write it up.)

Comment: @Pradhan isn't `2^S` same as `2^n` since size of |s| = n? I'd love to see a DP solution nevertheless :)

Comment: @kuriouscoder The first observation you can make is that the maximum sum is achieved when every number in the array is included, i.e. a mask of all 1's.

Comment: @kuriouscoder In the example you gave, `n = 5`, while `S = 2`.

Comment: @Pradhan Oh great then! I was meaning you mentioned 2^|S|. Would you DP be `O(4n)` then?

Comment: @user3386109 Good point. Curious if we all 1's are reachable from any step when S = 2, how about S =3 and so on.

Comment: That is the crux of the problem. All 1's is not reachable from any starting mask when S=2. I'll give you a one-word hint: parity.

Comment: Could you show us an actual example? Complete input, complete output?

Answer (score 1):

Start off with the trivial observation that you would never apply your given bitmask `G`, which simply consists of `S` `1`s, more than once on the same stretch of your original mask, `M` - this is because bitwise xor is commutative and associative allowing you to reorder as you please, and xor'ing a bitmask to itself gives you all `0`s.

Given a bitmask `B` of length `S`, and an integral index `ind` in `[0,n)`, let `BestSum(ind, B)` be the best possible sum that can be obtained on `[ind:n)` slice of your input array `k` when `M'[ind, ind + S) = B`, where `M'` is the final state of your mask after performing all the operations. Let us write `B = b.B'`, where `b` is the MSB and consider the two possibilities for `b`:

1. `b = M[ind]` : In this case, you will not apply `G` at `M[ind]` and hence `BestSum(ind, B) = b*k[ind] + max(BestSum(ind + 1, B'.0), BestSum(ind + 1, B'.1))`.
2. `b != M[ind]` : In this case, you will apply `G` at `M[ind]` and hence `BestSum(ind, B) = b*k[ind] + max(BestSum(ind + 1, (~B').0), BestSum(ind + 1, (~B').1))`.

This, along with the boundary conditions, gives you a DP with runtime `O(n*2^S)`. The best solution would be max over all `BestSum(0, B)`.

Note that we have brushed all reachability issues under the carpet of "boundary conditions". Let us address that now - if, for a given `ind` and `B`, there is no final configuration `M'` such that `M'[ind, ind + S) = B`, define `BestSum(ind, B) = -inf`. That will ensure that the only cases where you need to answer unreachability is indeed the boundary - i.e., `ind = n - S`. The only values of `(n-S, B)` that are reachable at `(n-S, M[n-S:n))` and `(n-S, M[n-S:n) ^ G)`, thus handling the boundary with ease.

Answer (score 0):

Would the following work?

Use DFS to expand a tree with all the possibilities (do one flip in each depth), the recursion's ending condition is:

1. Reached a state of all masks are 1
2. Keep coming back to the same position, means we can never reach the state will all masks are 1. (I am not sure how exactly we can detect this though.)